# Change button My Location for FAB

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I change google map my location default button by another, for example a floating action button?

This is mi XML

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.skybus.skybus.view.MapsActivity"
    />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/menu_fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/margenes_fab"
        app:fab_addButtonSize="normal"
        fab:fab_addButtonColorNormal="?attr/colorPrimary"
        fab:fab_labelStyle="@color/colorAccent"
        fab:fab_labelsPosition="left">

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/accion_ubicacion"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="?attr/colorAccent"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/map_marker"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_title="Ubicacion" />

        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/accion_ruta"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            fab:fab_colorNormal="?attr/colorAccent"
            fab:fab_icon="@drawable/bus"
            fab:fab_size="mini"
            fab:fab_title="Ruta" />

    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want that the floating action button with ID "accion_ubicacion" have the functionality of the my location button from Google.

I hope all of you can help me, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have successfully initialized **`GoogleMap`**, you have two options:

1. Use the built-in method to display *user's current location*. You can use [`GoogleMap#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMyLocationEnabled(boolean)) method on the `GoogleMap` object to show the current location of the user and display a floating action button like Google Maps app.
2. If you want to display *custom* UI on top of the `MapFragment` then you need to do some extra steps.

   - Set some padding around the `MapFragment` using [`GoogleMap#setPadding(int, int, int, int)`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setPadding(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). This is to make sure that you don't hide/obscure Google's logo and copyright notices. You can read more about it [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding).
   - After you've added the padding and prepared your UI (which I guess you've already done), add a click listener on your button and trigger location update on `GoogleMap` object.

Sample code may look like this:

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

if (null != location){
  // map is an instance of GoogleMap
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
        .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
        .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
        .tilt(40)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));       
} else {
  // cannot retrieve user's location.
  // fallback to display some generic location
}
```

Make sure to add appropriate permissions (`ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` or `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`) in your manifest in either case to get user's location. Starting with API 23 you may have to explicitly ask the user for their permission.